# WPF Parent Window Binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, parent-child

I need to do something that seems pretty simple, but I cant make it work. I have a textbox in a child window and a button in the parent window. I need to bind the button content on the parent window with the textbox content from the child window. Please! I need a rope! thanks!

Comment: Are you using MVVM? Depends on what is behind the Window answer can differs, so if you have ViewModels for both Windows this is good, if just standard control's code behind - solution will be an other

Comment: mmm not sure.. I'm not a WPF expert yet!! if u could write some examples or something.. or just give some ideas to get some rope and begin my research for the solution!

Answer (score 2):

Use one `DataContext` object for both, and bind accordingly

Comment: are u able to be more specific about it? I'm not an expert on WPF yet!